# Are C++ std::hash implementations always deterministic?

Tags: c++, hash, std

I know that `std::hash<T>` are implementation dependent, but are they supposed to be deterministic?

I know if I ran the `std::hash<T>` function on a value in the same process multiple times, I would get the same output. However, if I restarted the process, would I get the same value? Is there a seed that is used for std::hash? Does it depend on the compiler version, or some other factor?

Is there a guarantee that with an input `X` I will always get output `Y` regardless of when the process running was started, the machine, or the compiler version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, and [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) clearly says that:

> Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the same input within a **single execution of a program**; this allows salted hashes that prevent collision DoS attacks.

emphasis is mine. This is since C++14, but we cannot assume that it would work C++11 as such guarantee was not provided explicitly.

Comment: do you have recommendations on a hashing algorithm that does produce the same result for the same input for multiple executions of a program?

Comment: There are plenty to choose from, you probably need to specify additional requirements. If you do not care about perfomance cryptohash could be a good candidate.

Comment: Criteria would be the same in the C++ documentation you've linked, except for that portion you highlighted. Changing from a single execution of a program to multiple executions of a program. If you can point me to resources where I can find such algorithms, or how to research for such algorithms, that would be helpful.

Comment: Then you can pick particular implementation of std, check if it has such property and use that explicitly in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Enabled specializations of `std::hash` satisfy the `Hash` requirements ([hash.requirements]), according to which

> The value returned shall depend only on the argument ... for the duration of the program.

There is no guarantee that hash values are stable across invocations, even if those invocations are of the same binary image on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [c++ standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash),

> Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the
>   same input within a single execution of a program; this allows salted
>   hashes that prevent collision DoS attacks.